# Does Elektra know who she is from the beginning?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-defenders

In series **Marvel Defenders**, Elektra was resurrected by the hand and she serves as the hand member throughout the series until the death of Alexandra. Through the series it shows that she always wondered about who really was before her death.

When Daredevil, Luke Cage,Jessica Jones and Iron Fist fight with the hand, at the final scene Matt stays behind believing that, He can talk with Elektra and tries to remind her who she is.

At the end it shows that while they were still fighting, Elektra said she loved Matt and she loved him since the day that she laid her eyes on him.

My question is,

1. Did she know the truth all along?
2. Why did she keep fighting even though she knew the truth at some point?
3. Why did she want to be the leader of the hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No she didn't know who she was all along Alexandra states this. Though I cannot find the exact quote. It goes alongside the lines of Alexandra saying "Some of your memories weren't worth keeping"
2. The reason she kept fighting after is because she wanted the elixir for herself. You can however see her struggling with REALLY hurting Daredevil.
3. This mainly had to do with the fact that she personally wanted to be free and do what she wants. As well as getting the elixir for herself

Comment: I thing under that mysterious look when Alexandra say those, at some point elektra knew. she knew some stuff at least. no way she was just empty back then,

I think she wanted to avoid being dead again. She said she saw the darkness and she didn't wanted to go back there. I think thats why she needed the immortality. to avoid being in that dark again.

for the third one, I think there'll be somethings more than just that.

thanks for the answer @KevinTheGreat